# Does innodb use snapshot to help replication of a new secondar like redis cluster?

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-replication

I am reading InnoDB replication and find that it uses binlog for secondaries to replicate primary node. This is strange to me to find that "secondaries download the binlog to replicate". Wouldn't it be more efficient to get a snapshot of the primary node first, and then append binlog for new changes just like what Redis cluster do?

So what is the true process of the replication between a newly added secondary node and a primary node?